# How to check if a given ip falls between a given ip range using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip

Please pardon for this trival question

Given a set of Ip the set is quite large and might increase
https://github.com/client9/ipcat/blob/master/datacenters.csv#L4

Small example set - **first column start ip second - end ip range**

[image]

I will get the user ip from the request . I need to check if the ip falls in these set of ranges . How do i accomplish this.

I have looked into [ip_range_check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip-range-check) and  [range_check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/range_check).

But they donot check for a ip given given range . How is thhis possible in node js with utmost performance. I dont want to go for a exhaustive search as performance is a hight priority.

Please help something new and quite challenging so far to me.

Comment: This might not be the most optimal way. But I suggest you to convert the ranges of IPs into CIDR then use ip_range_check to check if an IP belongs to the CIDR. I believe you can use [rangecalc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rangecalc) to convert the ranges to CIDR.

Comment: @Deja a small example will be really appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is quite easy if we convert the ips to simple numbers:

```
function IPtoNum(ip){
  return Number(
    ip.split(".")
      .map(d => ("000"+d).substr(-3) )
      .join("")
  );
}
```

Then we can check a certain range as:

```
 if( IPtoNum(min) < IPtoNum(val) &&    IPtoNum(max) > IPtoNum(val) ) alert("in range");
```

That can also be applied to a table:

```
const ranges = [
  ["..41", "192.168.45"],
  ["123.124.125"," 126.124.123"]
];

const ip = "125.12.125";
const inRange = ranges.some(
  ([min,max]) => IPtoNum(min) < IPtoNum(ip) &&   IPtoNum(max) > IPtoNum(ip)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but taking into account the large ip set will it be fast or give a good performance of the ip we need to check resides at the bottom of the table

Comment: @infosys one could optimize it through converting the table from ips to numbers once. ( and i think further optimizations require big memory consumtion ) And have a look at *bloom filters*, they might do what youre looking for.

Comment: Thanks i will convert ip to numbers not an issue that function wont be required but what is bloom filter how to add it to that and search ?. I will up vote the answet and accept it too

Comment: @infosys youre welcome ;) , as i said, if you use big tables for lookup (e.g. every ip address is stored as a boolean), then you have huge memory consumtion, but its very fast. Bloom filters do that with smaller memory but with loosing precision.

Comment: I looked into bloom filters it like a hashtable of java. But how to insert the ip range and get the ip range this might be another question that hits my mind . Or how to search the bloom folter with min max?

Comment: @infosys you cant *search* . the table would be huge. Thats a simple memory vs. performance discussion. And yeah, that would be a few other questions...

Comment: may be you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203516/given-a-list-of-ranges-how-can-we-find-if-the-given-value-exist-in-that-list-of

Comment: Does this not fail for IPv6 values with letters, like `8592:757c:efae:4e45::`?

Comment: @dmitrizzle yes. The original question was about a list of IPv4s, and apparently the question did become somewhat popular in the last five years. This answer was never meant to last

Comment: In the meantime pyBlob has written the answer I would write for this question today.

Answer (score 12):

Starting with Node.js v15, we can also use `BlockList` from the native `net` package:
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netblocklist

We can create the BlockList object, populate it with the relevant entries from the table:

```js
import { BlockList } from "net"

const blockList = new BlockList()
blockList.addAddress("123.123.123.123")
blockList.addRange("10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.10")
blockList.addSubnet("8592:757c:efae:4e45::", 64, "ipv6")
```

and test if the list matches individual addresses:

```js
console.log(blockList.check('123.123.123.123'));  // Prints: true
console.log(blockList.check('10.0.0.3'));  // Prints: true
console.log(blockList.check('222.111.111.222'));  // Prints: false

// IPv6 notation for IPv4 addresses works:
console.log(blockList.check('::ffff:7b7b:7b7b', 'ipv6')); // Prints: true
console.log(blockList.check('::ffff:123.123.123.123', 'ipv6')); // Prints: true
```

Answer (score 9):

```
//Use getCIDR from rangecalc
getCIDR("5.9.0.0", "5.9.255.255")
//This return 5.9.0.0/16

//You can then use ipRangeCheck from ip_range_check
ipRangeCheck("IP TO BE CHECKED", "5.9.0.0/16")
//returns true or false
```

Pretty sure there's other way to do this.

Comment: This would work but this will be exhaustive right like brute force. Something more performance wise will be better as we have huge ip range dnt you think. Still a solution none the less

Comment: This might be helpful [iptrie](https://github.com/postwait/node-iptrie)

Comment: Quick reminder about Tries: They are not good memory-wise. So you're exchanging memory for performance