# Given a list of ranges how can we find if the given value exist in that list of ranges in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, intervals, interval-tree

I have aset of ip ranges and i need to find if the ip given by the user exists between the given list of ip ranges .

This is in continuation to this question

[How to check if a given ip falls between a given ip range using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200086/how-to-check-if-a-given-ip-falls-between-a-given-ip-range-using-node-js)

Jonas helped me get the ip exists or not. But i donot want to do a exhaustive iterative search , I want to go a fast performance intensive search as my list of ip ranges (or number ranges) will be huge.

I looked into bloom filters as pointed by jonas but i am not convinced bloom filter might help . Also i was looking at [Interval Tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-interval-tree) But i dnt think it can search interval it takes intervals as inputs.

My ip list ranges https://github.com/client9/ipcat/blob/master/datacenters.csv#L4

How to search it in a fast manner . I am using node js

Comment: What´s wrong with linear comparisson? Unless you have over 1 million ranges shouldn´t be a great concern

Comment: @juvian just to confess it is a ad server blacklist ips and here i need to get it done in a matter of milliseconds and the data will get added here i:e more ip ranges in future. and there are other processes to too related to ad serving so this needs to be quick

Comment: Can there be multiple matches?

Comment: no it should happen , i just need to give like a true and false does it exists in the ip range ot not

Comment: If they are non overlapping ranges you can convert them to number ranges, keep them sorted and then each query can be made in log n comparissons, but you would need to keep all in memory

Comment: sorting and keeping it in memory is another reason i  need to use some other techniques, because i will fetch it from db and want to just run a query on that array of objects

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193477/fast-algorithm-to-quickly-find-the-range-a-number-belongs-to-in-a-set-of-ranges

Comment: Well if you are using a db then you can store them as number ranges and your db query would already search between the ranges

Comment: sorry @juvian i mistook in memory this list be pouplated only one at model  build stored as apart of the build in model , i dnt want to overprocess the model

Comment: Did not understand, do you make 1 db query for each ip you want to check or you retrieve all from db once and then process each ip you want to check